# Pipenv install development package not available on other window

Tags: python, pipenv

Pipenv noob here, here is what I did, I had 2 terminal windows open:

1. `pipenv install -d django_extensions` on terminal window 1
2. `pipenv run pip freeze` on window 1 and shows the package
3. `pipenv run pip freeze` on window 2 and cannot find the package

Tried `exit` and `pipenv shell` on window 2 again, and still cannot find the package.

UPDATE 1: the package shows up on a newly opened window.

Comment: Try running `pipenv --venv` in both terminal windows. This will show the directory with the virtual environment that pipenv is using. If these two directories differ, this might be the reason why pip shows different sets of packages.

Comment: thanks @MikhailBurshteyn looks like I have 2 different locations